# easyrsa - почему в сертификате Public-Key: (384 bit) вместо Public-Key: (2048 bit)?

Tags: linux, rsa, openvpn, encryption

Не знал как еще придумать название поста, уж не бейте))

Ситуация такая:

есть 2 сервера

1. "open-vpn-001" на нем развернут PKI easyrsa + openvpn
2. "client1" на нем easyrsa + openvpn (последний исп. чисто как клиент)

На сервере "client1" генерирую запрос на подпись
(в конфиге ~/easy-rsa/vars директивы установлены так

```
set_var EASYRSA_ALGO ec 
set_var EASYRSA_DIGEST "sha512"
```

),

командой

```
./easyrsa gen-req client-5 nopass
```

и передаю файл client-5.req на сервер "open-vpn-001", где подписываю этот запрос и на выходе получаю сертификат client-5.crt

Не могу понять почему в сертификате указан алгоритм
Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey и размер ключа Public-Key: (384 bit) ???
Откуда взялись эти данные?

Но если я выполняю создание запроса на сервере "open-vpn-001", и на нем же его и подписываю, то в сертификате я получаю то что нужно
Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
Public-Key: (2048 bit)

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить, куда копать? Файлы vars на обоих серверах одинаковые!

- как надо - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/_NYTwNkKCYgseg
- как не надо - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/XOsftxQzfHfniA

Comment: вы же сами пишете: `set_var EASYRSA_ALGO ec` - алгоритм цифровой подписи на эллиптических кривых. Вы точно уверены, что у вас одинаковые `vars`? Может быть вы используете в командрой строке `--use-algo`? Добавьте в вопрос файлы `client-5.req` и `open-vpn-001.req` (команда `openssl req -text -noout -in reqfile.req`)

Comment: да vars точно одинаковые я с одного сервера "open-vpn-001" скопировал на другой "client1". "Может быть вы используете в командрой строке --use-algo?" - нет я использую только команду вида ./easyrsa gen-req client-1 nopass. "Добавьте в вопрос файлы client-5.req и open-vpn-001.req (команда openssl req -text -noout -in reqfile.req)" - Вот это не понял, почему команда другая? Я правильно понимаю что мне тогда на сервер клиентский "client1" не нужно пакет easy-rsa ставить?

Comment: Команда `openssl req -text` распечатывает содержимое файла `req` в удобочитаемом формате

Comment: openssl req -text -in /opt/easy-rsa/pki/reqs/client-5.req  А что мне дает это? Я по прежнему вижу что в запросе Public-Key: (384 bit) вместо 2048... только лишь понимание того что сам .req сформирован с использованием 384 bit.  Но почему!???  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g4c9SCLmKB2397g-tpkuI1FCJce2YqRl/view?usp=sharing